# How to build a static library on M1 mac that supports iOS simulator on Intel mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, universal-binary, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I have a fat iOS library which supports both real devices (arm64...) and iOS simulator of Intel Mac (x86_64). But when I switched to M1 mac, things get tough.

If I use the old library, I will fail with error saying `xxx.a (xxx.o) building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file 'xxx' for architecture arm64`. It seems that I have to build a xcframework which contains binaries for different destinations.

So I tried to build different slices and hope to bundle them as a xcframework. But I finally found I don't know how to build the x86_64 slice with a M1 Mac.

My question is

- how to build a static library on M1 mac that supports iOS simulator of Intel Mac?
- Or was my thinking wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason I failed to get x86_64 slice on M1 Mac is that there is a legacy option in my build setting: Valid architectures.

Remove this configuration and run standard flow. Then you will get library containing x86_64 architecture smoothly.

```
xcodebuild archive --destination="generic/platform=iOS Simulator" ...
```

If your library code is not organized as a Xcode project but uses clang toolchain underneath. You can refer to this [link](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#general-cross-compilation-options-in-clang). In a nutshell, specify target in a format like arm64-apple-ios14.3-simulator

Comment: Thank you, I had an older project that had this exact same issue!  I trying many things but the destination generic/platform=IOS Simulator was only producing an intel binary... I removed two instances of this from my project.pbxproj file: ["VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = x86_64;] (removed the whole line) and the build command starting building frameworks with x86 and ARM binaries.